# Can I maintain separate spring configuration file for each project?

Tags: c#, spring.net

Scenario: 
I am already using spring.net for basic configurations/object that are needed by application to startup. This spring configuration file, and the startup objects, are part of xxHost project.

Problem:
Now, I need to instantiate objects that are in project XXProvider and xxHost doesnt has any reference to xxProvider.

As a code sample:

```
//All object exist in xxProvider.csproj, and are used for internal logic
var runnerInstance = new FirstRunner(new List<IFieldMatcher>
                                           {
                                             GenericBuilder.Build("ProductId"),
                                             GenericBuilder.Build("IsReceiver"), 
                                             GenericBuilder.Build("QuantityUnit")
                                           });

//Need to remove this instantiation to a spring config file!!!!
//and to be able to write something like this...
var runnerInstance = SpringSettings.FirstRunnerInstance;
```

Is there a way I can maintain a csproj exclusive spring file?
Is there a way I can lazy load a separate spring file which is not loaded with application startup?

Any appropriate document/reference would be of help.
Thanks for your interest!